# CoinGeckoApi not responding in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety, coingecko

It used to work and the image of the coin was displayed, but for several days this error is displayed instead of the image of the coins.
[image: error]

[image]

```
 FutureBuilder(
                                                    future:
                                                        getCoinDataDogeCoin(),
                                                    builder: (context,
                                                        AsyncSnapshot<
                                                                CoinGeckoResult<
                                                                    prefix
                                                                        .Coin?>>
                                                            snapshot) {
                                                      return (snapshot
                                                              .hasData)
                                                          ? Center(
                                                              child: Image
                                                                  .network(
                                                                      "${snapshot.data!.data!.image!.small}"),
                                                            )
                                                          : CircularProgressIndicator();
                                                    }),
```

[image]

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that will reproduce the specific issue

Comment: Please check again

Answer (score 0):

As error , it is getting null data and you are using `!`. Try checking if the value is null or not

```dart
if(snapshot.data?.data?.image?.small !=null) Image(....
```

Here we are accepting null with `?` and using `!` after checking not null.